# Confused about multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I have made a program consisting of several classes and files. It reads some input from USB, processes it and writes it to a CSV-file. It's an ongoing process spitting out CSV-files several times a day based on user configured time periods where the program monitors the USB-input.

I am writing another script to read each CSV-file, when all the USB-input for the period has been written to the file.

Since I don't want to interrupt the ongoing USB-hid-reading process, I would like to utilize the multiprocessing functionality in Python and spawn a temporary handler each time a file is ready for processing.

So far I've made this little test script that takes the location of the CSV-file as input and prints out the content, while the parent process keeps on running.

```
import multiprocessing
import csv


class Handler(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self, period: dict = None, csv_file: str = None):
    super().__init__()
    self.period = period # dict containing configuration from parent 
    self.csv_file = csv_file

    def run(self):
        with open(self.csv_file, newline='') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
            for row in reader:
                print(', '.join(row))
```

The child process is started from and instance of a class called Period. Each period represents a user defined time period in witch to read USB-data. When a CSV-file is closed a child process is started from the perioed-instance in the following way:

```
    p = handler.Handler(self.period,self.csv_path)
    p.start()
    # the program continues to execute, writing more csv-files and starting more handlers
```

The above seems to work as intended. However in theory a lot of processes could be spawned this way.

**Ideally I would like to feed CSV-paths together with the period-configuration from each period-instance into a queue which would be processed by just a single child process across the entire app and not a new child process for each period.**

**I have read about queues, pipes and pools but I'm not really sure how to go about it. So I'm looking for any input to help me on the right track.**

The processing of the CSV-files are not time critical, the reading from the USB-device is.

Also the waste majority of multiprocessing examples I've seen are using a call from __main__ Something to do with how Windows cannot fork child processes the same way as Unix.

I have one __main__ method in my program (in main.py) and it is really not ideal to implement any of the above logic in there. That is why I ended up overriding instead. Not sure if that is the way to do it though.